# XFCE4 Taskmanager alternative that can show each CPU core usage, instead of just one graph

Tags: linux, task-management, debian

For Debian 11, I need to check CPU usage per core (just like Windows), not just one percentage for the entire CPU.

Which one is the best to use on XFCE?

Comment: Have a look at conky, the system monitor for linux, integrated on the background - so always visible!

Comment: @KenMollerup [There seems to be something like this on conky](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367538/display-clock-frequency-per-core-using-conky). I'll give it a try later.